# Associate file extension with air app on Android

Tags: android, file, air, invoke, associate

I am trying to associate a file extension with my air app on Android. My goal is to be able to start my app by clicking on a file with a specific file type from either a file manager or mail app. I have found a solution that in theory would work in native, but does not with air somehow.

In the .xml-file for the app, under the  tag I have written:

```
<activity>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.csml" />
        <data android:host="*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Does anyone have an idea how this could be solved?

Thanks in advance
Jens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe AIR currently doesn't support intents, [here the feature request for it](http://ideas.adobe.com/ct/ct_a_view_idea.bix?c=9D564F43-979A-4E35-AA21-85A61B6AB8DE&idea_id=EEF3EC13-E28F-41CC-AE7D-D47CE06E03CE).